# Duplicate Meta Description on Product Images in Google Webmaster

Tags: product-images, gallery, meta

I am showing 185 duplicate meta descriptions on product images. All the product images have unique alt tags, how to you update the meta description for the images?

[image]

Comment: Also, all the actual products have unique meta descriptions as well.

Comment: What is this screenshot exactly?

Comment: it's a screenshot from Webmaster Tools showing duplicate meta descriptions

Answer (score 3):

Generally the image's alt description comes from the "Label" field saved for the product image. Snippet from the base theme's default code:

```
<p class="product-image product-image-zoom">
    <?php
        $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
        echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
    ?>
</p>
```

If the values saved on the products are not what is being sent to Google, check some of this stuff:

- Make sure indexes are up to date and that what is sent to Google is the same as what is saved on the product image's label.
- Check your product image template, default is `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml` - Make sure the alt tag is using `$this->getImageLabel()`
- Maybe you have another module that is rewriting the media block and is doing something different with `getImageLabel()` - You'll have to look through installed modules to find if something is rewritten.